# PowerShell Custom Formatting Properties

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, format, powershell-cmdlet

When using the `Get-Volume` Cmdlet in PowerShell, I noticed that numbers are formatted with units and divided down when displayed as output. For example:

```
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
C                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      7.35 GB 118.63 GB
```

But, upon closer inspection with `Get-Member`, it appears that `Size` and `SizeRemaining` are just regular `UInt64` types. Calling `ToString()` on `Size` just yields `127377920000`.

Is it possible to apply this effect to the properties of `PSCustomObject`s?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you create a PSCustomObject, you can define the DefaultPropertySet that will get displayed when you reference the object. You can also customise the TypeData for the object's properties (although naturally the PSCustomObject inherits the TypeData of any object referenced in it).

For Powershell-native commands like `Get-Volume`, a .ps1xml formatting file defines a command's output format, but it can be done inline within a script with the above methods.

[Everything You Wanted to Know about PSCustomObjects](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject) by Kevin Marquette goes into a lot of detail about DefaultPropertySet and TypeData, with different methods for defining them and links to more info. I highly recommend reading the whole thing, because there's too much detail to include here (without a specific example).